# Illegal Cell Type Error, POI Apache

Tags: apache-poi

I'm trying to export my primefaces datatable into .xlxs using POI. But when I try to do so, an error shows up in the console: `Illegal cell type`. I have imported all needed libraries and placed all .jar files inside my classpath.

Here is my code:

```
 for (int c = 0; c < _col_cnt; c++) {
            //Construct the header row
            String _h = HeadersLabel[c];
            XSSFRow row = s.createRow((short)c);

            if (_h != null) {
                // Label label = new Label(c, 2, _h); //
                XSSFCell title = row.createCell((short)c,2);
                title.setCellValue(_h);
            }
```

The error I face is

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal cell type: 6
org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell.setCellType(XSSFCell.java:769)
org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow.createCell(XSSFRow.java:177)
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure those are you only calls to `createCell` ? Only it looks a lot like somewhere in your code you're calling `createCell(columnNumber, 6)`

Comment: I call 'createCell' in in several places..... what could be a error there ? @Gagravarr

Comment: When you call createCell, you can optionally give it a second argument to tell it the type of the new cell. That type needs to be a valid type!

Comment: so how can I declare the type of the cell in the above code ?

Comment: You are, your above code looks fine. Somewhere else in your code is what's causing the problem! Look for where you call `createCell` with the invalid cell type `6`

Comment: I thought no need to specify setCellType while we are creating .xlsx ?

Comment: It isn't required, POI will figure it out when you set the value, but it can be quicker. You either need to set it to a *valid type* or not set it at all. Setting an invalid type won't work, as you have discovered